# Magento Add Information in Checkout Shipping method Progress Block

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, shipping-methods

I would like to add `Delivery instructions` info under Shipping Method in progress block of the `checkout` page.

Please advise where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/progress/shipping_method.phtml
```

copy in your package and change there

```
app/design/frontend/yourpackage/default/template/checkout/onepage/progress/shipping_method.phtml
```